# simplePie: substring description without removing the images for every news

Tags: php, laravel, rss, simplepie

hello im trying to limit the text of every single news , my code works fine like this

`<p> {{ substr(strip_tags($item->get_description()), 0, 500) }} </p>`

but one thing i noticed, it removes all of the images of the news. is there any tricks to avoid that? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `strip_tags` lets you specify tags not to strip out. So, you can specify not to string out `<img>` tags. You'll also need to change your blade output tags to `{!! !!}` so that the html won't get escaped (assuming you're on Laravel 5).

```
<p> {!! substr(strip_tags($item->get_description(), '<img>'), 0, 500) !!} </p>
```

Comment: thankyou for the response sir but it didnt works fine for me, btw, im on laravel 4.2

Comment: Since you're on L4, you can use `{{ }}`. Are you saying this didn't work?

Comment: no sir, now I got it I just have to raise the limitation number from 0 to 600 or higher. thankyou sir @patricus